# What is the difference between these two examples of code?

Tags: autohotkey

I have been using `While GetKeyState("<some key>", "p")` everywhere for best part of a year without really thinking about what is actually happening.

```
space::
While GetKeyState("space", "p")
    {
     MyVar++
     Tooltip, % "MyVarIs: " MyVar
     Sleep 500
    }
```

Is the above `Tooltip` command, essentially **only** triggering every half a second?
if so then how is the following working? Since `Sleep 500` is absent:

```
space::
if GetKeyState("space", "p")
    {
     MyVar++
     Tooltip, % "MyVarIs: " MyVar
    }
```

I am thinking it should only fire once. To fire again I have to release and press `Space` again, but that is not the case. The Tooltip command continuously fires just like in the While example.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first Tooltip command is triggering every half a second because of `Sleep 500`.

The second is continuously triggering if the key is holding down:

```
space::
; if GetKeyState("space", "p") ; redundant
    ; {
     MyVar++
     Tooltip, % "MyVarIs: " MyVar
    ; }
return
```

To make it fire only once (by releasing), use the Up variant:

```
space Up::
     MyVar++
     Tooltip, % "MyVarIs: " MyVar
return
```

or the [KeyWait](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/KeyWait.htm) command.

Comment: Aah so thats what it was. `space up::` is just brilliant. Thank you